# Bash search through elements in array

Tags: arrays, bash, csv, categories

Lets assume that I have a huge list in csv file, that describes problems with software\servers\programs\etc.
I need to categorize this problems by categories.
Example of problems (in file Output_data.csv):

```
Multiple issues with IBM WebSphere MQ
Update to Oracle DB
MS SQL is not working
RDBMS not work
```

For this purposes I think i can define array with categories:

```
declare -a arr=("Websphere" "Oracle" "MS SQL" "RDBMS")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
# bind every problem to their category
done
```

And all problems are goes from $problem_text variable in loop

```
while IFS= read -r current_escalation; do
# strip problem from $current_escalation
problem_text=$( echo $current_escalation | cut -d',' -f7 )
# determine category for $problem_text
# ????
done <$DIR/Output_data.csv
```

**My question is how to search through every element of array to determine category of issue** for example, by keyword? e.g Issue "Multiple issues with IBM WebSphere MQ" = Websphere ? I think to use for this purposes dictionaries in bash for multiple keywords. Example:

```
declare -a Websphere=("IBM" "Websphere" "MQ")
```

But I don't have much experience in Bash and cannot understand how to put this together. Or, maybe you can suggest me another, more easy way.

Comment: Did you consider doing a grep on the issue against all the categories? Would that work? I guess an issue can belong to several categories as well. Anyway I think a string match is easier than doing list arithmetics like intersect and diff.

Comment: This type of data processing is faster and easier in a general purpose programming language.